# icCube with olap4php

Tags: php, olap-cube, iccube

We started to build a PHP application to connect to icCube and I want an example for olap4php, because I couldn't find it anywhere in the icCube documentation.

In particular, I need the Provider to use in building connection object to icCube.

```
// Example for Mondrian
$connection = new Connection(

    new SoapAdaptator('http://localhost:8080/mondrian/xmla'),
    array(
        'DataSourceInfo' => '**Provider**=Mondrian;DataSource=MondrianFoodMart;'
        'CatalogName' => 'FoodMart',
        'schemaName' => 'FoodMart'
        )
);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Olap4Php is using XMLA protocol, the catalog is icCube's schema :

```
$properties = array(
   XMLAConnection::PROP_CATALOG => 'Your icCube Schema'
);

$connection = new XMLAConnection( 'http://localhost:8282/icCube/xmla', $properties );
```